# How to enhance User Experience of Qt list item widget as of MS office tools?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qlistview

I'm making a widget for some reordering purpose. I want to make it much like this Outlook Dialog Box :

[image: MS Outlook Rearrange Commands tool]

For the menu list items, I'm using Qt List Widget and adding an icon with a text.
The UI doesn't look very pleasing.

Is there any way in Qt to make the icon panel different in color as shown in this Outlook dialog box?

Also how can I add icons on right side also, as in case of multi level menus have right arrow.

Comment: Try `QTableView` instead, with 3 columns. You might have to implement your own Item Model, based on `QStandardItemModel`, in order to provide the different columns

Comment: I think you might want QTreeWidget/View. It is basically a QListWidget with multiple columns. You can set each item's background color.